# How to end Ubuntu-one related processes automatically?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, couchdb

I am running Ubuntu-one on my Maverick machine. Since I do not want it to sync my data all the time I have removed it from the startup programs. So, whenever I want my files to be uploaded to the cloud I manually start Ubuntu-one and keep it running until it's done. Sadly, the related processes such as beam.smp or syncdaemon continue to run and consume lots of memory. Ending all these processes manually is a way to go, but it isn't really convenient. Is there any way to simply end Ubuntu-one after syncing with just one click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`u1sdtool --quit` works for me.

If it's not available by default, it will be in the ubuntuone-client package.

You would need to manually create a launcher for this to have one-click functionality.

You can right-click on your desktop if you're running Gnome/Unity to create a launcher, or add the file with nano, gedit or the editor of your choice:

e.g., **~/Desktop/u1shutdown.desktop** :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Icon[en_US]=gnome-panel-launcher
Name[en_US]=U1 Shutdown
Exec=/usr/bin/u1sdtool --quit
Comment[en_US]=
Name=u1sdtool --quit
Comment=Shutdown ubuntuone-syncdaemon
Icon=/usr/share/app-install/icons/ubuntuone.png
GenericName[en_US]=Shutdown ubuntuone-syncdaemon
```

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, I could advise using an .sh file with 'sudo killall -9 ubuntuone-syncdaemon' in it. And, put it on your desktop.